# How to develop an android SMS View?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to develop a view in android that is similar to the compose SMS view. I am not really familiar with all android view elements.

It is obvious that this view uses some textfields. But I want to know what layouts are in use. E.g. when the user enters some text in the message field the Grey field expands.

How can I achieve this and what else can you say about this view?

[image]

Comment: You should have tried atleast :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            a:orientation="vertical"
            a:layout_height="wrap_content"
            a:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <EditText
                a:id="@+id/smsRecipients"
                a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:hint="@string/sms_to_whom"/>
        <Button
                a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                a:text="@string/sms_contacts"
                a:onClick="onPickContact"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout a:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  a:orientation="horizontal"
                  a:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  a:paddingTop="5dip"
                  a:paddingBottom="5dip"
                  a:paddingLeft="5dip"
                  a:paddingRight="5dip"
                  a:background="#dcdcdc">
        <EditText
                a:id="@+id/smsBody"
                a:layout_width="0dip"
                a:layout_height="wrap_content"
                a:layout_weight="1.0"
                a:autoText="true"
                a:capitalize="sentences"
                a:nextFocusRight="@+id/send_button"
                a:hint="@string/sms_enter_message"
                a:maxLines="10"
                a:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                a:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"/>
        <LinearLayout a:orientation="vertical" a:layout_width="wrap_content" a:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <Button
                    a:id="@+id/smsSendButton"
                    a:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    a:layout_height="0dip"
                    a:layout_weight="1.0"
                    a:nextFocusLeft="@+id/smsBody"
                    a:text="@string/sms_send_abbr"
                    a:enabled="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is what you can write in XML file to get Layout like you want. You can change the color of the background layout or you can set image background, according to your needs. I just gave the color code for gray.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical">
         <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>   
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#A9A9A9"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:hint="Zum Schreiben eintippen"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Senden"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you have an example of SMS received message view?